# JQuery on Click for CSS not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have JQuery code to change a css of ID. If I use `event hover`, it runs well. But when I change it to a `click event`, it doesn't work, there is even nothing showing up in the console log. I have created a snippet here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#donatenow").click(function(){
 console.log("klik klik");
  $("#subdonate").show();
  }, function(){
  $("#subdonate").hide();
 });
});
```

```css
.subdonate{
 float:left;
 margin-top:-45px; 
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://buymebook.com/assets/cat/School%20and%20College%20Text%20Books.jpg" style="margin:20px;" class="promo3" id="donatenow" /><br />
   <div class="subdonate" id="subdonate">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://p3cdn4static.sharpschool.com/UserFiles/Servers/Server_1110080/Image/books.jpg" style="margin:20px;" class="promo3" /></a><br />
    <a href="#"><img src="http://p3cdn4static.sharpschool.com/UserFiles/Servers/Server_1110080/Image/books.jpg" style="margin:20px; margin-top:-25px;" class="promo3" /></a>
   </div>
```

Does anyone know why my jquery fails? What I want is, when I click the first image, the second and third image show up, but when I click again, the second and third image will hide again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/aqm7kjbg/4/

just change your jquery.

```
var count = 1;
$("#donatenow").click(function(){

    if(count % 2){
        $("#subdonate").show();
        count = count + 1;
    }else{
       $("#subdonate").hide();
        count = 1;
    }

});
```

Comment: Perfect! So the problem is click event can use 2 event at once? Because if I use hover, it works good. I can accept Your answer in 8 minutes. Thank You

Comment: @CrossVander yes... don't forget to check if this helps you... =) happy coding.